# Change a datetime variable to be only the year of the variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a date variable called `DOB`. I just want to update the table so `DOB` is just the year of DOB

First plan was update

```
  @table set @variable = convert(int, year(@variable))
```

or something like

```
  set @variable = year(@variable)
```

but it tells me first off I cant convert datetime to int

I then try and say

```
DOBint = year(DOB)
```

and so forth, but I cant drop DOB in the end because

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The statistics 'DOB' is dependent on column 'DOB'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN DOB failed because one or more objects access this column.

Even though this is a database I just copied from a server to my machine to play with and test on.

```
drop statistics traveldoc.DOB
```

doesn't do anything

and

```
select * from sys.stats where name = 'DOB'
```

It seems there should be an easy way I can do this without dropping/adding columns and then renaming columns

Simple way to just strip day and month from a date and keep it on the same variable?

I am using SQL Server 2008

Thanks

edit:
larger part of my function

```
DECLARE @action nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @table nvarchar(128);
DECLARE @variable nvarchar(MAX);

DECLARE rowCurser CURSOR FOR SELECT [Column1], Column2, Column3 FROM tempdb.dbo.DataAvailableForAnalysis;
OPEN rowCurser;
FETCH rowCurser INTO @table, @variable, @action

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @action = REPLACE(REPLACE(@action, '@table', @Table), '@variable', @variable);
--if OBJECT_ID(N'@table',N'U') IS NOT NULL
--BEGIN
EXECUTE(@action);FETCH rowCurser INTO @table, @variable, @action
--END
END
CLOSE rowCurser;
DEALLOCATE rowCurser;
```

in this case the @action for this variable would be

```
declare @variable datetime   update @table  set @variable= DATEPART(YYYY,@variable)
```

Update #2:

So I think adding some context would help
I have a table full of actions for certain variables/tables

such as

```
create table ##actiontable
(
actionname nvarchar(max) ,
tablename nvarchar(128),
variablename nvarchar(max)
)

insert into ##test3
values ('update @table set @variable=1', 'NcsAnalytics13.dbo.ReplicationObject', 'Target' )
```

In this case the variable target would be set to 1 in the table NcsAnalytics13.dbo.ReplicationObject

My real ##actiontable is full of different update statements for different variables. The only one I am having trouble updating is the DOB where I want to strip the day and month off the variable (this is to eliminate personally identifiable information). I need to keep the same variable name but having a hard time being able to create new variable, drop old one, and rename since for some reason there is some statistic connected to DOB that I cant figure out, so I cant drop it.

Comment: it doesn't matter really i guess since your doing a replace and it ultimately winds up as a nvarchar so just cast 

REPLACE(REPLACE(@action, '@table', @Table), '@variable', Cast(DATEPART(YYYY,@variable) as varchar));

Comment: I guess the only problem is that only some of the actions would be doing the datepart, so I would need to do that only for those particular variables...can I do an if statement within a cursor to do different replace statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably just add a new computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE tempdb.dbo.DataAvailableForAnalysis
  ADD DobYear AS YEAR(DOB) PERSISTED;
```

and then you have both the actual complete `DOB` as well as the `DobYear` column available

Answer (score 3):

You want datepart

@variable = DATEPART(yyyy,@Variable)

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp

> ```
> Declare @variable datetime,
>         @converted int,
>       @converted2 datetime
>
> Set @variable = GetDate();
> Set @converted = Cast(DatePart(yyyy, @variable) as int)
> Set @converted2 = Cast('1/1/' + cast(@converted as varchar) as datetime) 
>
> select @variable;
> Select @converted;
> Select @converted2;
> ```

UPDATE based on your update

```
DECLARE @action nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @table nvarchar(128);
DECLARE @variable datetime;

DECLARE rowCurser CURSOR FOR SELECT [Column1], Column2, Column3 FROM tempdb.dbo.DataAvailableForAnalysis;
OPEN rowCurser;
FETCH rowCurser INTO @table, @variable, @action

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @action = REPLACE(REPLACE(@action, '@table', @Table), '@variable', cast(DATEPART(yyyy,@variable) as varchar));
--if OBJECT_ID(N'@table',N'U') IS NOT NULL
--BEGIN
EXECUTE(@action);FETCH rowCurser INTO @table, @variable, @action
--END
END
CLOSE rowCurser;
DEALLOCATE rowCurser;
```

Comment: It still tells me Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Comment: ok, that works if I am just using this alone, I run into this problem as part of a larger cursor function, if I define @variable to be datetime as part of that specific variable, would it mess up the other functions within the datetime?

Comment: edited my answer. @converted2 returns '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000'. i cant answer your question really because i have no idea what youre doing. I'd suggest running it as a select statement first and check your results to make sure theyre still what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter a column from date to int, so convert to varchar first, then extract the year and alter the column again to int.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ALTER COLUMN DOB VARCHAR(30)

UPDATE YourTable
SET DOB = YEAR(CAST(DOB AS DATE))

--SELECT * FROM YourTable

ALTER TABLE YourTable
ALTER COLUMN DOB INT

--SELECT * FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I run into the problem of `The statistics 'DOB' is dependent on column 'dob'.`

Comment: So do you have an index on there?  If so, can you just drop it and recreate?

Comment: I dunno, cant figure it out, drop index DOB on test.dbo.TravelDoc doesnt work, says it doesnt exist

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the structure of your table. I'm only assuming it's index-related because your earlier "drop statistics" command didn't work.

Can you find anything related to your column in the query below?
    `SELECT s.name AS statistics_name, c.name AS column_name, sc.stats_column_id
    FROM sys.stats AS s
    INNER JOIN sys.stats_columns AS sc 
    ON s.object_id = sc.object_id AND s.stats_id = sc.stats_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c 
    ON sc.object_id = c.object_id AND c.column_id = sc.column_id
    WHERE s.object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTable');`

Comment: Nothing shows up for the column name or table name...This is a new database I created as a test so very confusing